# How to intepret (const int & a) and new int (a), what does it do?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

```
int * myFun(const int & a) 
{
    int * c = new int(a);
    int b = *c;
    return &b;
}
```

1.How to intepret     `(const int & a)`      and     `new int (a)`   , what does it do?

2.Could you explain to me why there is a memory leak?

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: I added the C++ tag, but if it's not, change it to the real language tag.

Comment: If you don't know what a reference is, you might want to consult an introductory book to C++.

Comment: Note that in addition, using the return value will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Borgleader, And the other two questions are also easily found in an introductory book.

Comment: @user3342529 -1 This question was plainly copied from your exam question samples / textbook learned lessons exercises!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to pick a beginner book from [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), read it through and then start again.

On to your questions:

- `const int & a` is a const reference to an `int`, named `a`. Basically, it means something that points to another int variable somewhere, and behaves just like that int, except you can't change its value
- `new int (a)` means you dynamically allocate memory somewhere on the heap for an int variable, and initialize that variable with the value `a`. This expression returns the address of the variable you just created
- Why is there a memory leak ? You allocate memory with the `new int(a)` statement, but never release it. This should be done with:

  `delete c;`

before the end of your function.

As noted in the comments, this function has undefined behavior in the return statement, since you return the address of a local variable (You may need to actually read that C++ beginner book to understand what that means).

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the code, you are using c++

You get a new pointer `c` with the value of `a` then you make `b`, with the same value as `c`, you return `b`, leaving `c` as the leak because nothing points to `c` anymore.

At then end:

- `a` is the const
- `b` is the value of `c`, which is the value of `a`
- `c` is a pointer to a new variable that is no longer referenced in your code